# A book where balloons are used to capture peoples' lifeforce

Tags: story-identification

We read this book a while ago where the main character - a girl - befriends a boy and they realize that something is wrong with their parents. Turns out, they were going to this tree where they would blow air (their life-force) into balloons as payment. There is some kind of creature that offers deals and you have to blow your life-force into a balloon. He chooses specific colored balloons for each character and he chooses a yellow one for the main character.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site.